# Прокрутка без убирания псевдоэлемента

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, позиционирование, прокрутка

У меня есть выпадающий список со стрелкой сверху, заданной псевдоэлементом before:

```
body > nav .dropdown > menu {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 150px);
    margin-top: 90px;
    border: 2px solid #aaaaaa;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
body > nav .dropdown > menu:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -17px;
    left: calc(50% - var(--caret-position));
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: solid #aaaaaa;
    border-width: 2px 0 0 2px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

И я хочу сделать прокрутку в списке, если он превышает определенное значение высоты. Но т. к. before находится за границами элемента, при добавлении "overflow: auto" он скрывается. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы он не скрывался, при этом без добавления дополнительных элементов в html?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант обернуть дочерние элементы списка дивом и именно ему поставить `overflow-y: auto`.

```css
.list {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
  top: -20px;
}

.wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden auto;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нужно без изменения текущей структуры элементов. То есть только "список > before + элементы".

Comment: @IkorJefocur, тогда никак. Можно JSом обернуть, если неохота трогать html.